# Вызов функции по событию onclick

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся на интересное поведение в `javascript`, что при вызове функции с сигнатурой `click()` вызов этой функции не происходит. С чем связана эта особенность? Существуют ли еще подобные конструкции?

```js
function click() {
  console.log("click is called");
}

function doSomething() {
  console.log("doSomething is called");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="click()" />
<input type="button" value="doSomething" onclick="doSomething()" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что при создании обработчика таким образом он создается в области видимости кнопки. А там уже есть свой метод клик:

```html
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="console.log(this.click);" />
```

Чтобы обратится к глобально объявленной функции с таким именем, можно сделать это через window:

```js
function click() {
  console.log("click is called");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="window.click();" />
```